# Sqlite database browser in android

Tags: sqlite

> 

How can i attach the **database to my activity that i have created in sqlite database browser.
and *can i write queries in sqlite database browser and will it run in my activity*

Comment: Read the documentation and the examples at the developer site.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html  By the way, best practice is not to run database queries in your UI thread.  Use a CursorLoader.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in the following link. I think it will fully solve your problem.

[Populating SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263028/populating-sqlite-database/19263302#19263302)